# Start a conversation using bot.beginDialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using Node.js with the Microsoft Bot Framework. When the user opens a connection to my bot, for example, just using the simulator, I would like the bot to initiate the conversation with a welcome message and some basic instructions.

The [documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/UniversalBot/#proactive-messaging) says to use the `bot.beginDialog`, however, I cannot get their examples to work; they just throw a 500 error.

Does anyone have a simple, working example of using the `bot.beginDialog` method to initiate a conversation?

Comment: Also, another samples where the same is being resolved: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/search?l=JavaScript&q=conversationUpdate&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Thank you, the question you referenced above had the answer for me!